# Get tuples with intersections

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two columns which defining a person - *passport_id* and *driver_license_id*. And *passport_id* and *driver_license_id* uniquely define the person.

For moment in time there is only one unique combination of *passport_id + driver_license_id*. But one person can have multiple *passport_id* and multiple *driver_license_id*.

There is a table with these two columns contains all combinations:

```
passport_id | driver_license_id
111         | aaa
222         | aaa
333         | bbb
111         | bbb
```

How can I get unique *person_id* for every *passport_id* and *driver_license_id*?

For the example above it's one person, because 111 corresponding to *aaa* and *bbb* and it's mean that this person have 3 *passport_id* and 2 *driver_license_id*.

Comment: (1) How do you identify the "person"?  (2) What result do you want?

Comment: @GordonLinoff any passport_id and driver_license_id uniquely identify the person. I want to get person_id for every passport_id and driver_license_id by intersect all of them. For my example it should be one person_id, for example 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below example is for BigQuery Standard SQL with scripting

```
#standardSQL
DECLARE rows_count, run_away_stop INT64 DEFAULT 0;

CREATE TEMP TABLE input AS (
  select '111' passport_id, 'aaa' driver_license_id union all
  select '222', 'aaa' union all
  select '333', 'bbb' union all
  select '111', 'bbb' union all
  select '444', 'ccc' union all
  select '444', 'ddd' union all
  select '555', 'ddd' union all
  select '666', 'eee' union all
  select '777', 'fff' 
);

CREATE TEMP TABLE initial_grouping AS 
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(driver_license_id ORDER BY driver_license_id) arr 
FROM input
GROUP BY passport_id;

LOOP
  SET rows_count = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM initial_grouping);
  SET run_away_stop = run_away_stop + 1;

  CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE initial_grouping AS
  SELECT ANY_VALUE(arr) arr FROM (
    SELECT ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT val FROM UNNEST(arr) val ORDER BY val) arr
    FROM (
      SELECT ANY_VALUE(arr1) arr1, ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(arr) arr    
      FROM (
        SELECT t1.arr arr1, t2.arr arr2, ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT val FROM UNNEST(ARRAY_CONCAT( t1.arr, t2.arr)) val ORDER BY val) arr 
        FROM initial_grouping t1, initial_grouping t2 
        WHERE (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM UNNEST(t1.arr) val JOIN UNNEST(t2.arr) val USING(val)) > 0
      ) GROUP BY FORMAT('%t', arr1)
    )
  ) GROUP BY FORMAT('%t', arr);

  IF (rows_count = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM initial_grouping) AND run_away_stop > 1) OR run_away_stop > 10 THEN BREAK; END IF;
END LOOP;

SELECT passport_id, driver_license_id, final_grouping FROM input 
JOIN (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() final_grouping, arr FROM initial_grouping) 
ON driver_license_id IN UNNEST(arr) 
ORDER BY passport_id, driver_license_id;
```

with output

[image]

To apply above example to your real data - remove `CREATE TEMP TABLE input (...)` statement and replace `input` in `CREATE TEMP TABLE initial_grouping AS ...` statement with reference to your actual table `project.dataset.table`

Also, make sure you set appropriate max for run_away_stop (in above script it is `10` - see last statement within LOOP - you might need to increase it to make sure conversion will complete)